# How to order overlapping layers of bars in an SSRS range chart

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi-paginated-reports

I've got a range chart in SSRS and I want a timeline view of a vehicle's delivery route.  The route has several types of activity (driving, time at site, break etc.) and these should be marked by different colours on the chart. I've used DrawSideBySide=False to overlap the different values and got general the structure I need. Below is an example of what I have so far:

[Current timeline (see small gap on Sleeper12)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWVXQ.png)

I want to mark the drive time as blue and the rest as grey. Seems simple, but there are gaps in the dataset. That means I can't just line up all activities and colour everything in the properties. I get gaps that can't be filled.

However, I do have a *route_start* and a *route_end* field that I can use. This makes a solid bar the whole length of the route. So now I need to overlay the drive time bars over the route bars.

One more complication - the tables isn't in chronological order. I only get one bar per drive time on the chart when there are multiple on the route.

See an example of the table I have:

[Sample of table for one vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3NKR.png)

Driver times series must always be layered on top of the route length series. I was hoping I could use the order of the series in the chart data window but no luck. This is how I've set it up:

[Chart data setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2n3b.png)

Comment: Please post data as text not an image (or better still a script to recreate the data), that way readers can quickly copy it when trying to reproduce your issue.